# Copy folder in c

Tags: c, windows

What's the best way to copy a folder (and its entire contents) from adress1 (the address of the folder)  to adress2 in c? I don't want to copy it to a buffer and then save it because it might contain large files

Comment: The current c++ standard has no notion of folders. You may use `system()` and an appropriate command of your OS.

Comment: boost:filesystem, in case of C++ (you tagged it). In C - only platform API or  system()

Comment: For c++ please read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593608/how-can-i-copy-a-directory-using-boost-filesystem

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to implement this yourself, look into [this](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/143382-implementation-linux-cp-copy-command-c-language.html) code

If it's not that critical that you have implementation and you can use the operating system's `cp` command than just use `system('cp',...)` or `system('xcopy',...)` for Windows in your code.

Anyhow, every implementation will buffer some of the file for copying (you control the size of the buffer if you implement it yourself), for example:

Say you want to copy file X of size 10000 bytes
With buffer of size 100 bytes you will loop 100 times filling the buffer and writing to the target file

Comment: *"you can use the operating system's `cp` command"* - This is assuming, that the OS has a `cp` command. Windows doesn't, and since the question is specifically asking for Windows, I'm going to have to downvote this answer.

Comment: Will you upvoteit now?

Comment: No. The OP is asking for the *"best"* way. Invoking `system` is - arguably - the worst. Use the shell's optimized file and folder copying infrastructure. It's a lot better at reporting errors, can provide progress feedback, and is blazingly fast, when moving files within a single volume.

Comment: We will have to agree to disagree. I notice you didn't read the entire answer before downvoting which makes this discussion a waste of time

Comment: I read the entire proposed answer, and the shell's optimized copying/moving doesn't buffer any data, unless it must. Absolute statements are easily refuted with a single counter-example. In essence, you have a link-only answer, a poor `system()`-based solution, followed up by inaccurate statements. This is a case where the *"This answer is not useful"* option should be used.